# Python XML with Element Tree: Parsing nodes that meet multiple conditions/conditions on child nodes

Tags: xml, python-3.x, elementtree

Hi I am new to both Python and XML (good combo I know), and I appreciate the help. I have an xml doc that looks basically like this:

```
<root>
   <elementaryExchange elementaryExchangeId='alkjalj' amount='5'>
      <compartment subcompartmentId='52u0298452'>x</compartment>
      <inputGroup>'4'</inputGroup>
   </elementaryExchange>
</root>
```

Except there are many of these elementaryExchange nodes (I only care about the ones with inputGroup='4'). I'm trying to make a couple of lists in which each element corresponds to the same elementary exchange. My code so far:

```
    for j, LX in enumerate(root.findall(".//elementaryExchange/[inputGroup='4']")):
        o.append(LX.attrib['elementaryExchangeId'])
        p.append(float(LX.attrib['amount']))
        for c in root.find(".//elementaryExchange[@elementaryExchangeId==o[j]].../compartment"):       
            r.append(c.attrib['subcompartmentId'])
```

o and p seem to be working ok, but I can't seem to figure out the subcompartment id part. Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lists I wanted were o, p, and r in the above code for the elementary exchange ids, amounts and subcompartment ids respectively. I think I figured it out though - I just didn't understand how to work with xpath:

```
for LX in root.findall(".//elementaryExchange/[inputGroup='4']"):
    o.append(LX.attrib['elementaryExchangeId'])
    p.append(float(LX.attrib['amount']))    
for LXc in root.findall(".//elementaryExchange/[inputGroup='4']/compartment"):       
    r.append(LXc.attrib['subcompartmentId'])
```